# How can we display an animated output for watershed management in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Here i'm using Tomcat(7.0)+GeoServer(2.1.3)+Openlayers(2.11).

How can we display an output like Flow of water for the **forest watershed management** application.

I have to show the **water flow** Based on the slope range range of the area, rain fall(qty in mm), duration of the rain, and so on. 
For this right now I have only 2 methods to generate this output: 
1)1 is to fill the color of layer by percentage wise. 
2)2nd is to render the layer by percentage wise.

can Anyone guide me how it is possible in Openlayers?

All help is greatly appreciated...

Best Regards,

***RamRamesh***..:)